# compliance out of fear of recrimination

Tags: meaning-in-context

> When cohesiveness is low or lacking entirely, **compliance out of fear
>   of recrimination** is likely to be strongest.

I do not understand the bold part, because of the word "**out**". Does "**out**" belongs to "**compliance**" or "**fear**"? (In other words, is it ***"compliance out" of fear*** or ***compliance "out of fear"***?)

Comment: This [explanation of "out of"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/out%20of) might help until someone gets a chance to write a proper answer. *used as a function word to indicate origin, source, or cause. "a remarkable colt out of an ordinary mare" / "built out of old lumber" / "fled out of fear"*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

> compliance "**out of fear**"

@ColleenV's comment is helpful. To help understand what "out" means in this context, substitute it for "because":

> compliance "***because* of fear**"

It sounds a little awkward, but it gets the general meaning across.

I'd synonymize your phrase, "**compliance out of fear of recrimination**" as:

> The primary (or sole) reason for their compliance is their fear of recrimination.